# Three planar vectors $x,y,z$ such that $x$ is orthogonal to $y + z$ and $z$

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors

> Let $x$ be a non-zero vector, orthogonal to vectors $y + z$ and $z$, with $x, y, z \in \mathbb R^2$. Prove that $y$, $y - z$ and $z - y$ are orthogonal to $x$ and parallel to $z$.

To prove they are orthogonal I tried just by dot product, but how to do with the parallel question?

Comment: It's not true, in general. (In $\mathbb R^2$ it's true. If this is what you meant, please edit your question.)

Comment: It's in R², sorry to have forgotten. But other thing i didn't understand is why this doesn't work for R³ ...

Comment: Please, edit your question!

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R^2$, two vectors that are orthogonal to the same vector must be parallel to each other. This is how you get the "parallel to $z$" conclusion of the problem.

In higher dimensions, the above is not true. Subsequently, the "parallel" part fails. An example could be given in $\mathbb R^3$ by letting  $y,z$ be  horizontal and $x$ vertical.

Comment: Oh, now i get it, but is there a way to prove that vector z is a linear combination of vector y?

Comment: @user166452 Yes, in two dimensions. Because both $y$ and $z$ are orthogonal to $x$.